# Facebook SDK for PHP 5.3 that can work with the Graph API v2.x

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting following notification from Facebook every few days.

> Your app, is making calls to v1.0 of the Graph API which will be
>   deprecated on Thursday, April 30, 2015. Please upgrade your app to v2.0 or later by that date

I have already updated JavaScript SDK to use v2.0.

My existing Facebook PHP SDK is v.3.1.1

The problem is, latest PHP SDK requires PHP 5.4 or greater.
but I am not able to upgrade my existing PHP version 5.3 to 5.4 (my application code is not compatible with PHP 5.4)

Are there any other older version of Facebook PHP SDK that I could use, that can work with graph API v2.0 or later and still compatible with PHP 5.3?

Comment: You can still use the old v3 PHP SDK with API v2 – you just can’t specify the API version explicitly with it. So you can either wait, until v2 will be the default – or, to test how your app works with v2 before end of April, you can enable a migration in app dashboard that will make your app use v2 for all calls automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will enable the migration in app dashboard to see how it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A year 2020 update to my answer -

I am sick of Facebook first deprecating the PHP version, then its complete PHP SDK and I have also noticed, that with Facebook Javascript SDK it is possible to pass a fake Facebook user id to my Facebook Canvas web app.

So I have written a pure PHP solution for fetching basic user information - on the server side and without using any external libraries.

My script is based on the fact that Facebook POSTs a [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) parameter to all Canvas web apps.

You can see it if you add the following line at the top of the PHP script:

```
error_log(print_r($_POST, TRUE));
```

By parsing the "signed_request" parameter you get an "oauth_token", which can be used to fetch the "/me" GRAPH API page.

Here is my script and remember to replace the APP_ID and APP_SECRET by the values from the [Facebook dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps):

```
const APP_ID     = '1234567890';
const APP_SECRET = 'abcdefghijk';

$data            = parse_signed_request($_POST['signed_request']);
$oauth_token     = $data['oauth_token'];
$user_id         = $data['user_id'];
$photo           = "https://graph.facebook.com/$user_id/picture?type=large";

$me = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=$oauth_token"), true);
list($given_name, $family_name) = explode(' ', $me['name'], 2);

# TODO use the $user_id, $given_name, $family_name, $photo in your web app!

function parse_signed_request($signed_request) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', strtr($signed_request, '-_,', '+/='), 2);

    $sig  = base64_decode($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);

    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, APP_SECRET, true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        exit('Wrong sig');
    }

    return $data;
}
```